# C# built-in events

Tags: c#, delegates

After reading the following piece of code :

```
[SerializableAttribute]
public delegate void EventHandler<TEventArgs>
(
   object sender,
   TEventArgs e
)
```

Why did not Microsoft guys give Object type for the "e" parameter just like the sender parameter? am I missing something major here?

Comment: Yes, but why didn't they give a generic also for the sender?

Comment: @Mu'menTayyem because the sender is frankly far less interesting (and is sometimes simply `null`) - *most times* people *already know* who the sender is; occasionally they need to check "which button", but you can do that with a reference check without even knowing the type... and *some other times*: people use event forwarding, which is awkward to do if the signature changes between levels

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If they had done that, people would constantly have to cast the `args` parameter. The point is that you can do things like:

```
public event EventHandler<SomeInterestingEventArgs> SomeEvent;
```

and:

```
obj.SomeEvent += (sender, args) => Console.WriteLine(args.SomeSpecificProperty);
```

This is a convenient way of replacing the need to declare:

```
public delegate void SomeInterestingEventHandler(
    object sender, SomeInterestingEventArgs args);
```

which is what you would have to do without this.

Comment: That's what I thought also, but why not a generic also for the sender?

Comment: @Mu'menTayyem see the addition at the bottom, and my comment on your question

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot, mate.

Answer (score 3):

You can make your own event args class that has some useful properties on it. Like the mouse click event args (can't remember the proper name) has an X and Y prop to tell you what point was clicked. Thanks to generics you don't need the casting you would with just a plain old object. You'd just have

```
MyEventHandler<MouseClickedEventArgs>(object sender, MouseClickedEventArgs e).
```

And everything is strongly typed